# How can I get the unique nested lists of a python list?

Tags: python, list, nested, unique

My question is related to the uniqueness of lists nested in a main list. Specifically, I have the following structure which is a list which includes `lists`:

```
lst = [  [
            [14], ['walk'], [69], ['walk'], [7]
         ],
         [
           [14], ['walk'], [69], ['walk'], [7]
          ],
        [
          [30], [948], [75], [947], [10]
        ],
        [
          [14]
        ]
   ]
```

In order to get the unique elements of the list I tried το implement the following:

`unique_data = [list(x) for x in set(tuple(x) for x in lst)]` but I am getting the following error:

`TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` .

The expected output is the following:

`[[[14], ['walk'], [69], ['walk'], [7]],`

`[[30], [948], [75], [947], [10]],`

`[[14]]]`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
lst = [
    [[14], ["walk"], [69], ["walk"], [7]],
    [[14], ["walk"], [69], ["walk"], [7]],
    [[30], [948], [75], [947], [10]],
    [[14]],
]

out, seen = [], set()
for subl in lst:
    t = tuple(tuple(i) for i in subl)
    if t not in seen:
        seen.add(t)
        out.append(subl)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[
    [[14], ["walk"], [69], ["walk"], [7]],
    [[30], [948], [75], [947], [10]],
    [[14]],
]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you create a dict, and saving the values as key, so if order matter than you can solve this problem as

```
lst = [[[14], ['walk'], [69], ['walk'], [7]], [[14], ['walk'], [69], ['walk'], [7]], [[30], [948], [75], [947], [10]], [[14]]]
 
unique = {}
for sublist in lst:
    key = ''
    for sub_sublist in sublist:
            for value in sub_sublist:
                    key += '_' + str(value)
    unique[key] = sublist
 
print(unique)
# output -> {'_14_walk_69_walk_7': [[14], ['walk'], [69], ['walk'], [7]], '_30_948_75_947_10': [[30], [948], [75], [947], [10]], '_14': [[14]]}

result = list(unique.values())
print(result)
# output. -> [[[14], ['walk'], [69], ['walk'], [7]], [[30], [948], [75], [947], [10]], [[14]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `set()`, you need to convert all the lists (and sub-lists) to tuples.

Try this code:

```
unique = tuple([tuple([tuple(x) for x in y]) for y in lst])
unique = set(unique)
```

Comment: Though this removes duplicate inner collections; but it outputs Set of tuple. OP needs original List with given order. Please modify your answer to return List with given order.

Comment: You are right. I think it's obvious..
Here is the code:
list_again = [list([list(x) for x in y]) for y in unique]